Questions regarding bernoulli factories from Keane and O'Briene's original paper
I am currently going through the Keane and O'Briene conditions for bernoulli factory simulations. I am new to this branch of maths and hence have quite a lot of questions. I have attached snippets from the paper to point out to the exact places I am confused about.

In the part where they prove that f(p) is continuous, 
they say that $\mu_p\{X \in E_0(A), \tau_A \le N \} > \mu_{\pi}\{X \in E_0(A), \tau_A \le N \} - \epsilon $, where do we get this? Is it sufficient to assume that $\mu_p\{X \in E_0(A), \tau_A \le N \} \approx \mu_{\pi}\{X \in E_0(A), \tau_A \le N \}  $, but if it holds for $\tau_A \le N$ then it should also hold for $\tau_A \le \infty $, but we prove continuity itself by proving that $2\epsilon > \mu_{\pi}\{X \in E_0(A) \} - \mu_p\{X \in E_0(A)\} $

What is X exactly, I am slightly confused about the notation. In the starting part of the paper, X is called a random sequence, which makes sense for tossing a coin. Then in the above image(question 1) we see that they talk about $X_1,...,X_N$ basically which could again mean the sequence of coin flips. However, on a later page they define



which does not make sense for X being a sequence of coin flips. It would make sense if $X \in \{0,1\}$.

They have an iterative method to approximate f(p), basically $$f_{a+1}(p) = \frac{4}{3}(f_a(p)-\frac{1}{4}\mu_p(F_k))$$
in this they take $f_1(p) = f(p)$, and with a increasing each $f_a(p)$ is supposed to represent a better approximation of f(p). But if already for a = 1 we had f(p) then how are we improving on it.

Markov's inequality is generally given as $$P(X\ge t) \le \frac{E(X)}{t}$$ from this how do we get to



Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

What is the meaning you give to the word "factory" in this context ?

@JeanMarie: "Factory" means Bernoulli factory, or a simulation method that turns a "biased coin" (e.g., probability of heads is $p$) into a differently "biased coin" (e.g., probability of heads is $\sqrt{p}$).

@PeterO. could you help me clarify the questions that I have posted above? I know these might seem a bit too basic to ask, any help is greatly appreciated. I have actually been reading your work with bernoulli factories, and it has been extremely educational. Thanks

@Peter O. Thanks ! A pity that the asker hasn't answered him/herself.

The following is a partial answer.
In the sufficiency proof of Keane and O'Brien, a continuous and polynomially bounded function $f(p)$ is written as the following series:
$$f(p) = \sum_{a\ge 1}\mathbb{P}[Y = a] g_a(p),$$
where $Y$ is a discrete positive random variable that equals $n$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}(\frac{3}{4})^{n-1}$, and each $g_a$ is a polynomial with Bernstein coefficients limited to zeros and ones. Given that $Y = a$, the simulation uses $g_a$.  Let $b_0, b_1, ..., b_m$ be these coefficients.  Then if the number of heads among the first $m$ coin flips is $s$, then the simulation returns $b_s$.
